# Python Twitter Search API

Tags: python, twitter

I am wondering why this code does not return for every json object the desired text?

```
# import
import json
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream

# Authentication
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'hidden'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'hidden'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'hidden'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'hidden'

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

# TWITTER SEARCH
twitter = Twitter(auth=oauth)           
search_tweets = twitter.search.tweets(q='#google')
json_dump = json.dumps(search_tweets)

for line in json_dump:
    print(json_dump['text'])
```

It gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "twitter_streaming.py", line 46, in 
>       print(json_dump['text'])
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Arman Even if it is Python 2.7, `print()` works fine

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`json_dump = json.dumps(search_tweets)`

converted the search_tweets variable into a string containing JSON in it. The issue is then with this code:

```
for line in json_dump:
    print(json_dump['text'])
```

What this code does is iterates over the **characters** in json_dump (since json_dump is now a string), and then for each character, tries getting the ['text'] index from this character, which is obviously possible.

It seems like you need to convert search_tweets to a list of dictionaries instead, in order to make it work with your later code. However, without an example output of the search_tweets variable I can't say what exact code you need to do - if you could add the contents of the search_tweets variable that would be helpful.